# Deducing this inequality for $u\in H^1(a,b)$

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

In the following picture, $v,u \in H^1(a,b)$ with $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Well, I think there is a typo.

[image]

How do we get $$u(x)+\int^y_x u'(s)ds\leq u(x) +\sqrt{b-a} ||u'||_{L^2(a,b)}\ ?$$

I'm thinking they  $\int^y_x u'(s)ds=\int^b_a u'(s)\chi _{(x,y)}ds$, where $\chi _{(x,y)}$ is the indicator function, and we have $||\chi _{(x,y)}||=\sqrt{y-x}\leq \sqrt{b-a}$.

Finally, how do we obtain the 1st inequality involving $u(y)^2$? If we have $f\leq g$, then $f^2\leq g^2$ may not be true if $g<0$.
However, we cannot assume that $u$ is positive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, we cannot assume that $u$
>    is positive...

You're right, you should instead do the following with triangle inequality and Holder's inequality for integrals,
\begin{align} |u(y)| &\le |u(x)|+ \left| \int_x^y u' \right|\\ &\le |u(x)|+ \int_a^b |u'\chi_{[x,y]}| \\
&\le |u(x)|+ \|\chi_{[x,y]}\|_{L^2[a,b]} \| u'\|_{L^2[a,b]} \\&\leq |u(x)|+ \sqrt{b-a} \|u'\|_{L^2[a,b]}.\end{align}
Now you can  apply the given elementary inequality and conclude.

Comment: Hi Calvin, thanks for the answer. I edited my question regarding a typo in my indicator function. Sorry about that ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.,  you're welcome. (PS  what I had typed before was equally valid :) )